# color in guide Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have done an assignment via GUIDE Matlab, the idea of the application is that putting some numbers as a function then it would plot that.

I face a problem. when it would plot that the colors are dark, they should be bright. does anyone have any idea to make it brighter?
I defined colors like this:

```
color=[1,0,0;0,1,0;0,0,1;1,0,1;0,1,1;1,1,0;.3,.6,.8;.8,.6,.3;.3,.5,.4];
title_str=get_title(degree);
for i=1:degree
   index=find(Xr(:,3)==i);
   scatter(Xr(index,1),Xr(index,2),15,...
   repmat(color(i,:),size(index,1),1).*repmat(conv_rate(index),1,3),'filled') ;
   legend_val{i}=strcat(num2str(i),'th Region');
end

scatter(Xr(Xr(:,3)==0,1),Xr(Xr(:,3)==0,2),'k','filled') ;
legend_val{degree+1}='Diverge points';
legend(legend_val)
title(strcat('Basin of attraction:',title_str))
```

this is what I get:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1OFb.jpg

Comment: you are not using GUIDE though

Comment: A scatter plot is the wrong tool for this visualization. You should generate an image instead.

Comment: what do you mean by generating an image? you mean with imshow ro plot command?